$F$-points vs $\overline{F}$-points of a scheme
Let $X$ be a scheme over a field $F$. Could someone please explain why the set of $F$-points $X(F)$ can be viewed as a subset of that of $\overline{F}$-points $X(\overline{F})$?
What I know is that an element in $X(F)$ is a morphism $x: Spec(F) \to X$, and an element in $X(\overline{F})$ is a morphism $y: Spec(\overline{F}) \to X$. So would it be correct to assume that $y$ is the composition of $x$ and the morphism $Spec(\overline{F}) \to Spec(F)$ induced from the extension $F \subseteq \overline{F}$? If yes, then how can one explicitly prove the containment $X(F) \subseteq X(\overline{F})$, i.e. given $x \in X(F)$ how do I prove that $x\in X(\overline{F})$?

Prove that X(F) to X(F bar) is injective.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$From the embedding $F \subset \bar F$, you get the map $\alpha: \Spec \bar F \to \Spec F$. You can use this to define a map
\begin{align*}\alpha^*: X(F) & \to X(\bar F)\\  (x: \Spec F \to X) & \mapsto (x \circ \alpha: \Spec \bar F \to X).
\end{align*}
It remains to show that $\alpha^*$ is injective. Can you do this on your own?

I think if $\alpha$ is an epimorphism, then injectivity would follow. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether or not this is the case.
